# Vue JS Syntax error: "Unexpected Token, expected ,

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js

I am working on a Django aplication that has VueJS in it. I am new to Django and even newer to VueJS.

I am getting this error when I try to run my code:

> ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors
> 2:11:51 PM
>
> error  in ./src/router/index.js
>
> Syntax Error: Unexpected token, expected , (51:0)
>
> 49 |   }   50 |
>
> > 51 | })
> > | ^   52 |    53 | export default router   54 |
>
> @ ./src/main.js 5:0-30  @ multi
> (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080
> webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js

here is my router/index.js file contents:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Chat from '@/components/Chat'
import UserAuth from '@/components/UserAuth'

Vue.use(Router)

const router = new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/chats',
      name: 'Chat',
      component: Chat
    },

    {
      path: '/auth',
      name: 'UserAuth',
      component: UserAuth
    }
  ]
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (sessionStorage.getItem('authToken') !== null || to.path === '/auth') {
    next()
    }

  else {
    next('/auth')
    }

  }

})

export default router
```

What is the reason for the syntax error and how do I correct it?

Comment: Fix the indentation to be more consistent and I imagine the problem will be self-evident.  The call to `router.beforeEach()` seems structurally incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the extra bracket you have in:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (sessionStorage.getItem('authToken') !== null || to.path === '/auth') {
    next()
    }

  else {
    next('/auth')
    }
  }   <-----------
})
```

Please remove it, one tip use code editors, most of them will indicate this silly mistakes that you may not realize.